# Why Unity hasTile display False?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

Im created a 3d tilemap using free asset models as shown below:

[image]

and here is the code where I am trying to get its position:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {
       //read in another post that changing to vector 2 will help
       Vector2 mousePosition = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition;
       Ray ray = cameraMain.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
       //performing raycast
       if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
       {
           //checking if hit the collider of gameobject and checking if the renderer is not null
           if(hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Target>() != null)
           {
               Vector3 rayPosition = hitInfo.point;
                //Vector3Int posInt = grid.WorldToCell(hitInfo.point);
                Vector3Int posInt = grid.LocalToCell(rayPosition);
                //Vector3Int posInt2 = tilemap.WorldToCell(mp);

                //Shows the cell reference for the grid
                Debug.Log(posInt);

                // Shows the name of the tile at the specified coordinates
                Debug.Log(tilemap.HasTile(posInt));
                //Debug.Log(tilemap.GetTile(posInt).name);
                
            }
       }
   }
}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

I want to use getTile, but it keeps saying object reference not set to the instance of the object, so I used hasTile to check if the tile is there. For some reason it is displaying false. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Surely the -20,-13 is beyond your tiles.

Comment: yes, it came to me after ive posted it. And Ive no idea why its wrong, when I clearly referenced the grid along with the tilemap